# Escopo de variáveis em event attributes

Tags: javascript, escopo-de-variáveis

Sabemos que ao declarar uma variável com `var`, ela só perde o escopo global quando declarada dentro de uma função, por exemplo:

```
function f(){
   var a = "string";
   console.log(a); // string
}

console.log(a); // a is not defined
```

Diferentemente de `let` e `const`, que possuem também escopo de bloco:

```
for(var x=0; x<10; x++){}
console.log(x); // 10

for(let y=0; y<10; y++){}
console.log(y); // y is not defined
```

Pois bem. Vejam esses dois exemplos *com* e *sem* `var` na variável `nome` dentro do atributo de eventos `onclick`:

**1) Com `var`:**

```js
function f(){
   console.log(nome);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="var nome = 'Fulano'; console.log(nome); f()">Clique aqui</button>
```

**2) Sem `var`:**

```js
function f(){
   console.log(nome);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="nome = 'Fulano'; console.log(nome); f()">Clique aqui</button>
```

No exemplo **1** causa erro no `console.log(nome)` da função `f()` porque a variável `nome` ficou com escopo restrito dentro do atributo `onclick`.

Já neste exemplo abaixo, onde a variável `nome` é declarada com `var` dentro de um `href` com `javascript:`, a variável fica com escopo global:

```
<a href="javascript: var nome = 'Fulano';">Link</a>
console.log(nome); // Fulano
```

Como `onclick` e `href` são dois atributos bem diferentes entre si, é compreensível esse comportamento, mas o que não entendi é o porquê da variável `var nome` dentro do `onclick` não ter escopo global, já que, em todas as explicações que pesquisei, o `var` não tem escopo de bloco, apenas em funções.

Se o conteúdo de `onclick`, em tese, é apenas um código JavaScript comum, a variável `var nome` não teria que ter escopo global quando declara dentro de *event attributes*, como no exemplo **1** acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dando uma pesquisada, percebi que o atributo `onclick` na verdade é uma função, ou seja, tudo que estiver dentro do atributo fica dentro de uma função `onclick` que é chamada no clique.

Ao verificar no console as propriedades do elemento `button`, é exibida a função `onclick` com o conteúdo do atributo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como isso, ao utilizar `var`, a variável perde o escopo global porque o código do atributo é inserido na função do evento.

No caso do `href` isso não acontece porque o `href` não dispara uma função de evento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]